# Couldn't change the orientation in SplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am not much familiar with iPad app SplitViewController. I have used the SplitViewController in my app. When change the orientation from portrait to landscape, Masterview is hiding from splitView. Could you please any help me to sort out this issue.

I have attached my source for your reference.

Creating SplitViewController:

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

```
menuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuViewController] ;
masterNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

MainMenuDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MainMenuDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuDetailViewController" bundle:nil] ;
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] ;
detailNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;


self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
[self.splitViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];
```

DetailView Page:

## pragma mark -

## pragma mark Split view support

- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {

  barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Menu", @"Menu");
  [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
  self.masterPopoverController = pc;
  appDelegate.rootPopoverButtonItem = barButtonItem;
  appDelegate.masterPopoverController = pc;
  }

// Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
self.masterPopoverController = nil;
```

}

MasterView Button Tap:

[appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];

```
[UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];


NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];

[viewControllerArray removeLastObject];

if( viewMenu.hidden == YES)  // Main Menu
{
    if(btnMenu.tag == 1) // Service Report Form
    {
        if (!self.mainMenuDetailViewController) {
            self.mainMenuDetailViewController = [[MainMenuDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.mainMenuDetailViewController];
        appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.mainMenuDetailViewController;

    }

    if(btnMenu.tag == 4) // Signout
    {
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
        [appDelegate SignOut];
        btnSignOut.frame = CGRectMake(24,275,272,50);
    }
    else if(btnMenu.tag == 2) // Inquiries
    {
       if (!self.inquiryViewController) {
            self.inquiryViewController = [[InquiryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InquiryViewController" bundle:nil] ;
        }


        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.inquiryViewController];
        appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.inquiryViewController;
    }
    else if(btnMenu.tag == PageMasterSync)
    {

        if (!self.mastSyncViewController) {
            self.mastSyncViewController = [[MastSyncViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MastSyncViewController" bundle:nil] ;
        }
        appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.mastSyncViewController;
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.mastSyncViewController];
    }
    else if(btnMenu.tag == PageServiceReport)
    {
        if(!self.srListViewController)
       self.srListViewController  = [[SRListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SRListViewController" bundle:nil];

        appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = srListViewController;
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.srListViewController];

    }


}


}


[[appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:viewControllerArray animated:NO]; 
if(btnMenu.tag == PageReview &&  !viewMenu.hidden)
   [self.reviewViewController loadServiceReport];

[appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
[viewControllerArray release];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

With regards
Senthil[image]